# accessing class inside another class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="gridmasonry grid_accomodation select_room">
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/standard.jpg" alt="img_preview"  />
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>Standart Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/luxury.jpg" alt="img_preview" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>Luxury Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/family.jpg"  alt="img_preview"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>Family Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/vip.jpg"  alt="img_preview"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>VIP Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/deluxe.jpg"  alt="img_preview"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>Deluxe Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="item_grid item2">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="img_preview">
                         <h4 class="price"><span>&euro;20 </span>Night</h4>
                         <img src="~/Images/rooms/romantic.jpg" alt="img_preview" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="clsRoomType"><h4>Romantic Room</h4></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

I have a structure of DIVs as above. I need to get the text of DIV with the class "clsRoomType" on each time when i click on a DIV item with the class "item_grid item2"

I tried the below code, but it shows the text of all items

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".item2").click(function () {
            alert($(".item2").find('div.clsRoomType').text());
        });
    });
```

Current result: Standart Room Luxury Room Family Room VIP Room...

I want each item on each click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
alert($(".item2").find('div.clsRoomType').text());
```

with

```
alert($(this).find('div.clsRoomType').text());
```

That will give individual item.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".item2").click(function () {
        alert($(this).find('div.clsRoomType').text());
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for a class in a given element

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".item2").click(function () {
        alert($(this).find('div.clsRoomType').text());
    });
});
```

Comment: And how is that different.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".item2").click(function () {
    alert($(this).find('div.clsRoomType').text());
});
});
```

Demo 
    http://jsfiddle.net/mYa9c/